# Inefficient count function?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I was recently told that this is inefficient code.  I responded to the person that I agree and that it would be handled better at database or a gem that handles it via a database.  They disagreed and said you can make it efficient without using the database.  Can someone tell me how you can make this check work and be "extremely" efficient?

Basically, the function goes through every record and determines if a record with the same_value has more than 2 edits than the some_value of the current model.

```
class SomeActiveRecord < ActiveRecord::Base
    # Fields: some_value string
    def exceeds_edits?(value, max_edits = 2)
        self.class.all.each do |record|
            edit_count = (record.some_value.split('') - value.split('')).length
            return false if edit_count >= max_edits
        end
    end
end
```

So my argument is that you STILL have to pull every record in the database to compare the number of edits regardless of how you write this which makes it inefficient.

Can anyone shed light over this?

Comment: `record.some_value.split('')` what are you doing here? can you share a real expample ?

Comment: Well, I'm taking a string value and converting it to an array... so for instance:  "5555YYYXXX" would be ['5', '5', 5', '5', 'Y ', 'Y'...] and so on.  The doing the same with the value that is passed.  If any of the values change it would give me the number of "different" characters in the string regardless of their location.

Comment: it look lot of work on application side and I can totally understand why other person is complaining about it. I don't know what is reason behind storing string this way and comparing it with all records, ideally you can keep a flag which says this record has been changed or something so that you check only those record rather then comparing each one of them. you might want to update this flag while saving the record. other then that there is only so much you can do with this code. you may try doing the same at db level, need some more time to give you right direction..

Comment: It seems that your code things that there are no edits between `foo` and `foofoo`. Similarly, for `abc` and `cba` (and other permutations). Is this intentional?

Comment: Yes.  The lengths are always fixed at 7 and only interested in values that have changed by 2 characters regardless of location.